# append many string in list seperated by split()

Tags: python-3.x

If I write this code:

```
b=list()
b.append(input())
print(b)
```

Simply the output will be:

```
["My text"]
```

But i want output like that:

```
["My","text"]
```

so I wrote this code:

```
b=list()
b.append(input("Enter your text: ").split())
print(b)
```

but in there the output is:

```
[['My', 'text']]
```

If I use split(),I am observing there are creating list including list.Why this...?? And how can I solve this problem..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply write

```
b = input("Enter your text: ").split()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `b.extend(...)`. It will not add the list as one item but all items of the list.

```
b.extend(input("Enter your text: ").split())
```